# Can I use Summoning Glass immediately upon receiving it?

Tags: arkham-horror, arkham-horror-curse-of-dark-pharaoh

Do I have to wait until the arkham encounters phase of my next turn, or can I use this card immediately upon receiving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.  Since there's nothing on the card that tells you that you have to wait for it, the ability is used the first time it's requirements are met.